# Is the charging time of a battery relative?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

Can the charging time of a battery depend from one day or another?

I.e.: if I start charging my phone at a certain battery level, while shut down, will it always take the exact amount of time to reach a other certain level or can this change from day to day (and if so: how much?)?

Thanks for the enlightenment :)

Comment: *Probably*? I suppose you can measure it. The limiting factors are the charger and the phone, not the power grid.

Comment: There's a temperature sensor on your phone battery.   If it gets too hot, the charging process will be slowed or stopped.   The temperature will be dependent on the ambient (i.e. are you in a sauna or are you on an Alaska cruise?)   So the answer is "no", it will not always be exactly the same.